# Remove integrated account from Facebook iOS SDK

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk

1. Once I login into the [Facebook](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook) system using [iOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS_%28Apple%29) [SDK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_development_kit) 3.0.
2. Somehow my application will terminate without calling the logout event.
3. My current login is active in the browser or webview, and I want to remove that account
      information from the device. How can I remove it? (Programmatically call the logout event when
      terminating my application).

I tried `[FBSession activesession close;]`, but I am not getting the proper solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution. When your application has crashed and your session is still alive, at that time just check this method:

```
if([FBSession activeSession])
{
    [[FBSession activeSession] closeAndClearTokenInformation];
}
```

, in this application delegate:

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you click on the logout button, call the below method.

```
-(void)fbDidLogout
{
    [facebook invalidateSession];
}
```

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: you are right but This method will call after i press on logout button and my application is crash at this time not event will call.

Comment: - (void)fbDidLogout {
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"" forKey:@"access_token"];
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"" forKey:@"exp_date"];
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
 
 isLoggedIn = NO;
}